# Leaflet Markers

Tags: javascript, maps, leaflet, tilemill

I’m new to leaflet, and I’m trying to display the markers. The tutorials don’t seem to work for me. The map shows up fine, however I just can’t get a marker to display.
below is my sample code:

```
wax.tilejson('http://localhost:8888/v2/DigitalHumanities.json',
  function(tilejson) {
        var map = new L.Map('map-div')
            .addLayer(new wax.leaf.connector(tilejson))
            .setView(new L.LatLng(-17.1828,137.4609), 4);

    var markers = new L.marker(-17.1828,137.4609);
    map.addLayer(markers);

    var markerx = new L.marker(137.4609,-17.1828);
    map.addLayer(markerx);

  });
```

I’ve tried the samples in the tutorials i.e.: `.addTo(map);` , `map.addLayer(markers);` etc.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The L.marker constructor should be used as:

```
var markers = L.marker([-17.1828,137.4609]);
map.addLayer(markers);
```

You can check the API reference [here](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker)

Comment: Is that `new` supposed to be there? Its supposed to be a factory method isn't it.

Answer (score 1):

The actual syntax for creating leaflet marker is

```
L.marker(<LatLng> latlng, <Marker options> options? );
```

You can check the API reference [here](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker)

Below is your code

> correct code

```
wax.tilejson('http://localhost:8888/v2/DigitalHumanities.json',
  function(tilejson) {
        var map = new L.Map('map-div')
            .addLayer(new wax.leaf.connector(tilejson))
            .setView(new L.LatLng(-17.1828,137.4609), 4);

    var markers = new L.marker([-17.1828,137.4609],{clickable:true});
    map.addLayer(markers);

    var markerx = new L.marker([137.4609,-17.1828]);
    map.addLayer(markerx);

  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the working example here< https://jsfiddle.net/viswanathamsantosh/x63kzb31/ >. The below line would add a marker and also a popup to your map when clicked on the marker.

```
new L.Marker([46.947, 7.4448]).addTo(map).bindPopup('hello world!!!');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let markers = L.marker([-17.1828,137.4609]);
```

or

```
let markers = L.marker({lat: -17.1828,lng: 137.4609});`
```

then:

```
map.addLayer(markers);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by either using the factory or the 'new' keyword on the class (which I believe is what the factory does anyway. The difference is in the case used.

I believe these should both work the same way:

```
var markerx = new L.Marker(L.latLng(137.4609,-17.1828));
map.addLayer(markerx);
```

.

```
var markerx = L.marker(L.latLng(137.4609,-17.1828));
map.addLayer(markerx);
```

But you cannot combine them.